# Setup.exe is unable to find msi after adding version number to its name

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, windows-installer, setup.exe

In Post Build Event of my Installer project I have added a script that adds the version number to msi file. But when running setup.exe it is unable to find msi file. How to solve this issue

My msi looks like this: PP-1.0.0.msi

Comment: there should be some manifest or setup.ini configuration file from which Setup.exe is reading.

Comment: Hi,@Saad Bin Shafi.   How are you running your installer? Have you checked your msi file? You can try to see if you have a similar situation as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944351/prerequisite-installer-setup-exe-results-in-unable-to-locate-application-file).